# BOTO3: default settings for not-optional CloudFront ResponseHeaderPolicyConfig

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudfront

In my CloudFront policies I have a custom Response Header Policy for setting the Access Control Allowed Origins. When I add them to the AWS website, I can add some origins to the list, keep the rest of the settings at default and let the Security Headers (optional) all disabled. This all works fine.

[Screenshot of optional Security Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkfhR.png)

Now I want to update the list of allowed origins automatically in Python using Boto3. I can update the origins list of items and quantity by doing

```python
policy_config["CorsConfig"]["AccessControlAllowOrigins"]["Items"] = origins
policy_config["CorsConfig"]["AccessControlAllowOrigins"]["Quantity"] = len(origins)
```

However, when I then run

```python
cf_client.update_response_headers_policy(ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig=policy_config, Id=policy_id, IfMatch=etag)
```

The optional values for the Security Headers aren't optional anymore, resulting in this error:

```
Missing required parameter in ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig.SecurityHeadersConfig.XSSProtection: "Override"
Missing required parameter in ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig.SecurityHeadersConfig.XSSProtection: "Protection"
Missing required parameter in ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig.SecurityHeadersConfig.FrameOptions: "Override"
Missing required parameter in ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig.SecurityHeadersConfig.FrameOptions: "FrameOption"
Missing required parameter in ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig.SecurityHeadersConfig.ReferrerPolicy: "Override"
Missing required parameter in ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig.SecurityHeadersConfig.ReferrerPolicy: "ReferrerPolicy"
Missing required parameter in ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig.SecurityHeadersConfig.ContentSecurityPolicy: "Override"
Missing required parameter in ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig.SecurityHeadersConfig.ContentSecurityPolicy: "ContentSecurityPolicy"
Missing required parameter in ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig.SecurityHeadersConfig.ContentTypeOptions: "Override"
Missing required parameter in ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig.SecurityHeadersConfig.StrictTransportSecurity: "Override"
Missing required parameter in ResponseHeadersPolicyConfig.SecurityHeadersConfig.StrictTransportSecurity: "AccessControlMaxAgeSec"
```

My question is: is there a way to circumvent this or of not, what should the settings be for them to be the same as not setting these options through the web interface? Can I just put all `override` options to `False` and put some random option in the others?

I read [this documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudfront/client/update_response_headers_policy.html#), but that didn't give me the answer to my question.

Comment: what is `origins`?

Comment: It’s a list of origin urls that I previously captured through `origins = policy_config["CorsConfig"]["AccessControlAllowOrigins"]["Items"]` and then updated with the urls that need to be added.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.